# Alamofire: How to download zip files sequentially within UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I have `NSMutableDictionary` Array lists that I want to download. I am using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to download each of them. However, when the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` runs, all the zip files downloaded in parallel, which causes the app to hang, the UI to freeze, CPU use to go through the roof.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:updateAllCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("updateAllCell") as! updateAllCell!
    let row = self.bookArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSMutableDictionary
    self.updateBookList(row, progressView: cell.downloadProgressView, labelView: cell.lblDownloadPercent)    
}

func updateBookList(bookData: NSMutableDictionary, progressView: UIProgressView, labelView: UILabel) {
     let source = Utility().getContentsDirectory().stringByAppendingString("/\(fileName).zip")
     Alamofire.download(.GET, source, destination: destination)
     .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
         println(totalBytesRead) // update progressView and labelView
     }
     .response { request, response, _, error in
         println(response)
     }
}
```

Can they downloaded one by one sequentially? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the download calls are being made as soon as the table requests the cell in question, since Alamofire does everything asynchronously (and if it didn't you would be waiting for the files to download before you would even see the cells).

What you want to do is implement a stack that will queue your requests and you pop the next request as soon as the previous one is finished.

Comment: Now, i got the result by removing NSmutableDictionary.
In cellForRowAtIndexPath, i checked with indexPath.row.
if indexPath.row == 0 { self.updateBookList(row,...) }
In updateBookList, i removed like "self.bookArray.removeObject(bookData)". Thank for the reply.

Comment: Sorry, it's kinda hard to resolve the problem you're facing from your comment. Personally, I think you should reconsider downloading on "cellForRowAtIndexPath" as this also means you trigger a download every time a new cell shows up (I.e. when scrolling).